# undefined method forget for nil in test file - RailsTutorial 9.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, authentication

I am new to rails so please forgive the following noob question and thanks in advance...

I am following the [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/advanced_login) however, once I got to section 9.12 where we add the forget logic to sessions_helper.rb, I get the below error which is confusing to me since I see the forget method defined properly. The error occurs when trying to run the users_login_test.rb file

```
Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
NoMethodError: undefined method `forget' for nil:NilClass
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `forget'
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:42:in `log_out'
    app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:34:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Here is my Sessions Helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

Here is my user.rb:

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
end
```

Here is my failing testfile:

```
    require test_helper

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

 def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
 end

 test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: "", password: "" } }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

 test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                          password: 'password' } }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Simulate a user clicking logout in a second window.
    delete logout_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that I got ahead of myself in the tutorial and skipped a bit too far ahead by accident and added a second 'delete logout_path' to the test which was meant to demonstrate that the second call to delete logout_path in Listing 9.14 should raise an error due to the missing current_user. I just removed it and passed the test. I'll try to slow down as I continue through the tutorial :)

Comment: I was about to write the answer to read more.  Just focus on "9.1.4 Two subtle bugs"

Comment: Thanks @HithamS.AlQadheeb